# R dbconnect error

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql, dbconnection

Hi I'm trying to connect R to a MySQL database by using the following code.

`library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)
con<-dbConnect(dbDriver('MySQL'),user='root',password='pw',dbname='dbname',host='100.000.0.00')`

(the parameter are fake)

R give back the following error:

`Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: waiting for inital communication packet', system error: 138`

I have already try with Heidi to rich the database and it work fine. I do not understand why with R doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: do not work !!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> library(RODBCext)
>
> > sqlString <- "Select * from yourtable or sql query ;"
> >
> > dbhandle<- odbcDriverConnect('driver{SQLServer};server=Servername;database=databasename;trusted_connection=True')
> >
> > data <- sqlExecute(dbhandle, sqlString, fetch = TRUE)

Comment: I edited the above- it should work  . i had missed the assign sign after the dbhandle<-

Answer (score 0):

Do not work

` library(RODBCext)

```
    sqlString <- "Select * from yourtable or sql query ;"

    dbhandle odbcDriverConnect('driver{SQLServer};server=Servername;database=databasename;trusted_connection=true')

    data <- sqlExecute(dbhandle, sqlString, fetch = TRUE)`
```

Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver{SQLServer};server=xxxxxx;database=xxxxx;trusted_connection=true") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver{SQLServer};server=xxxxx;database=xxxxx;trusted_connection=true") :
  ODBC connection failed